# Why does Genesis not specifically mention the creation of water?

Tags: catholicism, genesis, creation

We read of the first day of Creation in Gen 1:1-4:

> "In the beginning when God created the heavens and the earth, the earth was a formless void and darkness covered the face of the deep, while a wind from God swept over the face of the waters. Then God said, “Let there be light”; and there was light. And God saw that the light was good; and God separated the light from the darkness."

We see that there is a specific mention of the creation of light which is essential for the sustenance of life. Of equal importance is water, but its existence appears to have been taken for granted in Verse 2. Going further to Verses 9 and 10 we read:

> "And God said, “Let the waters under the sky be gathered together into one place, and let the dry land appear.” And it was so. God called the dry land Earth, and the waters that were gathered together he called Seas"

Put together, those verses give the impression that there had already been water in the universe before God created the earth, but it was not considered as important as the light for the sustenance of life on the earth.

My question therefore is: According to Catholic Church, why does Genesis not specifically mention the creation of water?

Comment: The heaven (with its winds) and the earth (with its waters) were created in the beginning, in the first quoted paragraph. But creating something, and putting order into it, are two distinct things. Just like an initially amorphous embryo, slowly taking on human shape.

Comment: Air is not mentioned either, except for that which God introduced into Adam's nostrils. Rock is not mentioned. Metal is not stated.

Comment: This is additional info, not a Catholic answer. The Hebrew words for waters (mayim) and heavens (shamayim) are similar. The Talmud explains: "*Shamayim means esh umayim, [fire and water], which teaches that the Holy One, Blessed be He, brought them and combined them together, and made the heavens from them.*" ([Why are the words for "heavens" and "waters" so similar? - Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/119306/why-are-the-words-for-heavens-and-waters-so-similar/119308#119308). That is, the heavens themselves contain water.